# Error when I run a python script in task scheduler

Tags: python-3.x, task, windows-task-scheduler

I get an error when I run my python script in windows task scheduler. My script is taking some date from an excel file. And the error is " No such file or directory". How I can fix it

Comment: Are you specifying a full path the the excel file? Also, it would be easier to help if you posted your script source.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error " No such file or directory "

Triple check your locations in the python script by copy / pasting them and seeing if you can manually get there.

Comment: import time
import yagmail
import os

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("C:/Users/Andrada/PycharmProjects/Checker/masini.xlsx"))
def read_and_check():
    df = pandas.read_excel(path)
    df.to_csv('masini.csv', index=None)
    list = []
    with open('masini.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        day = datetime.date.today()